# Storing/loading conditional format info in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

is there a way I can store and later restore conditional formatting information? Upon selecting a cell, I want to 
1/ store the condformatting of the corresponding column/row in some arrays
2/ delete the condformatting of the corresponding column/row 
3/ change InteriorColor of column/row to something nice (so that I see a crosshair)
4/ upon selecting another cell, I want to restore the condformatting of the original column/row and repeat the process from 1/ for the currently selected cell.

I tried something like

```
Public condFmt1 As FormatCondition
Set condFmt1 = Range("A1").FormatConditions.Item(1)
...
Set Range("A2").FormatConditions.Item(1) = condFmt1
```

however the last line gives me a runTime error 438 - Object does support this property or method. Im probably assigning wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with it for an hour, I've found a way around using FormatCondition values in VBA.

This code copies my "A1" range's conditional formatting, which is set to change the font to **bold** if the value is `TRUE`

```
Sub CopyFormatCondition()

    Dim fC As FormatCondition
    Set fC = Range("A1").FormatConditions.Item(1)

    Range("A2").FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=fC.Operator, Formula1:=fC.Formula1
    Range("A2").FormatConditions.Item(1).Font.Bold = fC.Font.Bold

End Sub
```

Some properties such as `Type`, `Operator` and `Formula1` have to be set when the FormatCondition is being initialised, hence why I had to add a FormatCondition to the range's FormatConditions collection.

Other properties (e.g.  `Font` and `Interior`) can be set after the FormatCondition's Initialization.

Comment: Hello Francis, first of all thanks for help! I experimented with your solution a lot yesterday. I want my solution to be capable of working universally, hence I would like to copy not only the fond boldness, but all the other formatting stuff. I have, however, problems copying border formatting. I will return once I have the solution.

Comment: If it helps, I've found that the easiest way to get the names of the properties you need is to record a macro whilst creating the conditional formatting.

Comment: Splendid Francis, it helped me a LOT! Will post the solution soon.

Comment: Francis, it took me an afternoon to figure out that this thing is impossible. You hit a bottom when trying to store `Interior` properties - they are read-only and I coulnd't find what they refered to... So you can't do fC.Interior = cellXY.interior.. crap.

Comment: Have you tried `Interior`'s sub-properties? 

For example `fc.Interior.Color = cellXY.Interior.Color`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Excel 2007 or higher, you can achieve your goal also with a Non-VBA solution:

1. Use an empty cell in your worksheet/workbook as a trigger cell and set it to `TRUE`. For convenience, name this cell `DisableConditionalFormatting` or similar.
2. Select the active area of the worksheet (Ctrl-A) and insert a new rule -> use formula to determine which cells to format. As a formula set `=DisableConditionalFormatting`. No need to alter the format here.
3. After setting the new rule, make sure to select the checkbox `Stop if true` in the conditional formatting rule manager

No you can toggle the conditional formatting for the worksheet on and off by changing the cell `DisableConditionalFormatting`.

Comment: Peter, I am running Office 2003, but will try your solution as soon as we get to 2010! Many thanks!